# whose quotas are in use on a web app?

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello everybody out there,

When publishing a Google Apps Script as a Web App, executing the app as the user accessing the App, whose quotas are in use?

I mean, to whom belong the quotas that are in use, to the script owner or to the user accessing the App?

I am only certain that ScriptDb quota is from the script owner because ScriptDb is attached to the script, but not sure about any other quotas in use.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Fausto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you are going to do with the web app.
If your requesting user documents it's the quota of the user.

If your using scriptDb it's the script owner.

Comment: thanks Thomas, the Web App would use several services: Spreadsheets, Send Email, Docs, Contacts